# WordPress: "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy" in PageSpeed Insights

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, pagespeed-insights

WordPress: "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy" in PageSpeed Insights

I got a diagnostic result of `Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy` on my wordpress site.

I think this is a browser cache issue, and added the following `.htaccess` code.

But the problem has not been solved.

I think that something is wrong.

What should I fix?

```
#.htacess


AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 216000 seconds"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"
</ifModule>

ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested exactly what minimal time is to satisfy this criteria, but PSI prefers longer cache times, setting the expiration to one year usually satisfies this criteria.